# Gallery lose focus

Tags: android, focus, gallery

I wrote a code to upsize the selected image in my gallery, i don't know why everytime i scroll, gallery lose focus, here is my code.

```
gallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {

            if (lasview != null)
                lasview
                        .setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(130, 195));
            lasview = v;
            v.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(170, 230));

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // System.out.println("NOTHING SELECTED");

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself like this.

```
     <Gallery
        android:id="@+id/gallery1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/gallery1"
        android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/gallery1"
        android:nextFocusRight="@+id/gallery1"
        android:nextFocusUp="@+id/gallery1" 
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"/>
```

In the Activity

```
    @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT) {

        gl.onKeyDown(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT, null);

        return true;
    }
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT) {

        gl.onKeyDown(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT, null);

        return true;
    }
            return false;
```

}

It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try `lasview.getLayoutParams()`, and set the values on the retrieved LayoutParams instead.
Calling `setLayoutParams()` causes a redraw/refresh which might cause your problem.

Comment: the method getView itself cause lose focus, because it contain setLayoutParams, is there a solution please? because it is very important to me?

Comment: I guess you could also add `requestFocus()` to the gallery/view you want focused to force the focus after you have done a change.